# Choose one of the points (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1) at random.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Choose one of the points $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ at random. Let $X$ be the first coordinate and $Y$ the second. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

They would be independent since event $Y$ does not alter what event $X$ would be. Since $X$ could be either $0$ or $1$, regardless of what $Y$ is.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

A little more technical:  When you say that one of these four are chosen at random, I assume you mean that each of these 4 outcomes has a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$.  And, as such, the probability of $Y$ being a $0$ (or $1$) does not differ depending on whether $X$ is a $0$ or $1$

Mathematically:

$P(Y=0|X=0) = P(Y=0|X=1)$ (= $\frac{1}{2}$) and

$P(Y=1|X=0) = P(Y=1|X=1)$ (= $\frac{1}{2}$)

Even more general, events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $P(A) = P(A|B)$. And indeed we have:

$P(Y=0) = P(Y=0|X=0)$ (= $\frac{1}{2}$) and

$P(Y=0) = P(Y=0|X=1)$ (= $\frac{1}{2}$) and

$P(Y=1) = P(Y=1|X=0)$ (= $\frac{1}{2}$) and

$P(Y=1) = P(Y=1|X=1)$ (= $\frac{1}{2}$)

Comment: " events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $P(A)=P(A\mid B)$". Not so. Events $A$ and $B$ are said to be independent if $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ and since this is a definition, you can replace "if" by "if and only if" if you like. This definition holds even if $P(B)=0$ in which case the $P(A\mid B)$ in your definition is undefined.

Comment: @DilipSarwate You are correct! I should have just said 'if'. I'll correct that, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right. Event Y not depends on X. We don't have any condition.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. They **can** be independent if 'choose one of four points *at random*' means 'with uniform distribution' or, equivalently, 'with equal probability'.

However, although that is quite reasonable assumption, it is not defined in the problem, so we *might*  suppose a non-uniform distribution. And for probabilities, say, $$P((0,0))=P((1,1))=4/10$$ and $$P((0,1))=P((1,0))=1/10$$ we would get a significant correlation between $X$ and $Y$.